# Why don't attributes in XSLT need namespace declarations

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Why don't I have to specify the namespace for attributes of nodes in XSLT?

As an example, let's say I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<timeline xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns="urn:xmlsn:axpz_namespace">

<A>
   <B>
    <C key="in"> bval <\C>
    <C ind="ra"> bra <\C>
   </B>
<\A>
```

And my xsl file Header like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mms="urn:xmlsn:axpz_namespace">
```

A select statement for an attribute of C would look something like:

```
select="./mms:B/mms:C[@key='in']"/>
select="./mms:B/mms:C[@ind='ra']"/>
```

But it seems like if you have to specify that `B` and `C` are part of the mms namespace, then you should have to specify that `key` and `ind` are part of that namespace as well. I.e.

```
select="./mms:B/mms:C[@mms:key='in']"/>
select="./mms:B/mms:C[@mms:ind='ra']"/>
```

While it seems obvious that if you're specifying the nodes namespace to be in `mms` then it's attribute should be in there as well, it seems just as obvious that if you specify `B` to be within the `mms` namespace then `C` should be in there as well.

This may be a trivial question, and maybe one that simply depends on the XSL reader being used, but I'm asking because it made me curious as to whether or not you could mix namespaces along various nodes. For example, something like:

```
select="./mms:B/othernamespace:C[@mms:key='in']"/>
```

I'm using the Saxon8B reader, and I'm guessing that this syntax is potentially dependent on which reader I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unprefixed attributes are always in "no namespace".**

And Jon Skeet's answer is like this:

> "Because the W3C namespace Spec says so"

**Let me explain the reasoning behind such a design decision**:

The logic is that an attribute is fully defined by the element on which it appears, therefore if the elements belongs to a specific namespace, there is no need to specify that any of their attributes belong to that (or other) namespace.

To put it in other words, attributes don't need a namespace to disambiguate them as is the case for elements -- because an attribute is fully disambiguated by the element it belongs to.

Therefore, it is a bad idea when designing a new XML-based vocabulary, to define attributes as belonging to a namespace.

An exception of this common-sense rule is for attributes that are with *global* scope (can appear on any element). Examples of such attributes are: `xml:lang`, `xml:space`, ..., etc.

Comment: I commented above why I liked Jon Skeet's answer. But, as you mention, I really was seeking the *reasoning* behind the decision, rather than just the evidence of the decision. Skeet's answer has some containment of this: "the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear". But, it is not as explicit as yours, so I've switched your answer to being the correct one.

Comment: Also, I did suspect this reasoning in my post, but I'm still curious why you have to specify namespaces for children nodes. After all, isn't their namespace fully defined by the parent node? But my guess is that while *all* attributes' namespaces are fully defined by their nodes, not all nodes are. Maybe it would be just a bit too clunky to say, "always specify a node's namespace, unless it's a child node". ??? Not sure

Comment: @smaccoun, I believe the reason for not treating element children as attributes is that attributes form a (flat) sequence, while an element is at the top of a tree of descendent elements. This makes it possible to have a subtree at some descendant, that itself is an instance of another XML vocabulary -- and the namespace is what distinguishes one XML vocabulary from another.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, and is exactly what I was wondering...wasn't sure whether or not you could have a subtree that is an instance of another XML vocab. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Although `xmlns=...` sets the default namespace for *elements*, it doesn't set one for *attributes* - you only get a namespace in an attribute name if you specify it explicitly.

It shouldn't depend on which XML API you use at all.

From ["Namespaces in XML 1.0"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting):

> 6.2 Namespace Defaulting
>
> The scope of a default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself.
>
> A default namespace declaration applies to all unprefixed element names within its scope. **Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names**; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.

(Emphasis mine.)

Note that this isn't about XSLT or XPath really - it's about plain XML and XML namespaces.

Comment: +1 because this: (a) points out that this is a general XML issue rather than just an XSL/XPath issue and (b) cites the XML documentation and the specific part that describes namespaces for attributes

Comment: That said, my question was mostly seeking the reasoning for w3's decision, and I wanted an answer which really focused on this. I originally accepted this as an answer because I felt the last line of the XML doc you cited somewhat describes this, which states "the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear" -- much as I suspected. But, I think Dimitre's answer is a little more explicit and points out any exceptions (which I also really wanted to know), so I'm choosing to switch. In any case, great response, amazed at how fast it was :)